# how can i update value from the value in checkbox

Tags: php, html, checkbox

i have 2 checkbox that deliver the different value..

```
<input type="hidden" name="position[]" value="<?php echo $excheck['check_id']; ?>">
<input name="position[]" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php if($pos == $poss) echo 'checked = "checked"'; ?> value="<?php echo $eq['pos_unit_name']; ?>">
```

its for determined whether it is checked or not..

if it not checked , then the value is still delivered which is the `check_id`..

the problem is, if another checkbox is checked, and the current checkbox is remain, how do i add the code?

this is currently my code..

```
$check = $_POST['position'];
foreach ($check as $id)
{
    if(is_numeric($id))
    {
        $up = mysql_query("delete from checklist where check_id = $id");
    }

}
```

what i want to accomplish is , if its unchecked, the data is deleted based on the `check_id` and if another checkbox is checked , insert a new data, and if the checked box is remain checked, then it just updated the value based on the `check_id`

Comment: try to print_r($_POST) and see the array structure. because your element name is not "position" it is "position[]"

Comment: well the checkbox is in the `while` loop .. i didn't mention it in my code.. sorry..

Answer (score 0):

First need to use unique name for each form fields. you have two fields name as **position** so use different name

and query var should be quoted like

```
$up = mysql_query("delete from checklist where check_id = '$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do in this case is to add the identifier as the key:

```
<input name="position[<?php echo $excheck['check_id']; ?>]" value="1" />
```

And then:

```
foreach ($_POST['position'] as $id => $checked) {
    // do stuff with $id
}
```